# Having css issues div ahref showing up behind others, domino effect

Tags: html, css, padding

I have a href button that I styled to have a blue padded border.
Here is how it looks.

[image]

It is stacking behind the header and the search bar and I cant figure out why.

If anyone can help me out. here is the html code of the 3 divs.

```
<div id="topnav">
    <span>Home &#187; Tutorials &#187; How to show an example</span>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="buttons">
        <a class="btn" href="">Recent</a>
    </div>
    <div class="form-main">
        <form class="form-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for tutorials ...">
            <select>
                <option value="7" selected="selected">All</option>
                <option value="1">Newbie</option>
                <option value="2">Beginner</option>
                <option value="3">Novice</option>
                <option value="4">Educated</option>
                <option value="5">Expert</option>
                <option value="6">Professional</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the css code:

```
#topnav {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#main {
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#buttons {
    text-align: center;
}
.form-main {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-color: #dedede #bababa #aaa;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 8px;
}
.btn {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2972a3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add display:inline-block; to your button style

```
.btn {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2972a3;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 17px;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This happens, because default value for "display" is "inline" for "a" element.You can read more about this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: thank you for the support, It was such an easy fix, thats so weird it was doing that. Should I always be defaulting to adding that every time I make any style for a link or button?

Answer (score 1):

You  is positioned after the size of its parent, #buttons, which get its height based of the height of your  content, which is 20px, but the real height of your  is 40px, which means 10px, both top and bottom, will be outside #buttons div.

Try adding `display: inline-block` to your button class (`.btn`) to make the parent get the size including the padding.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/yc31unad/